# What angular units does the QGIS raster calculator use: Degrees, Radians, Gradians?

Tags: qgis, slope

I am working with QGIs and am converting a slope raster with values in degrees to a slope raster with values in percent using the raster calculator and the following formula:

```
(arctan(slope_raster))*100
```

My original slope raster in degrees has no values outside of the 0-90 degree range which is expected but the percent slope raster it generates gives me a low of -62000 which is pretty silly.

I guess my question is what angular units does the QGIS raster calculator use? Degrees? Radians? Gradians?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raster calculator uses radians, so you'll have to convert your angular units.

To get from angles to percent slope, you need to use `tan`, not `arctan`, though, since `tan(angle) = opposite / adjacent`.

The following raster calculator expression should do the job:

```
tan("slope_raster" * 3.14159 / 180) * 100
```

Comment: I would like to help those who want to get degrees out of slope percentage in the raster or field calculator: atan("Naklon_pro" /100) /3.14159*180